# Only Able to Decrypt Encrypted Data First Time

Tags: c#, encryption

I have the following code to Encrypt/Decrypt PII data.

```
public static class Encryption
{
    public static readonly int KeyLengthBits = 256; //AES Key Length in bits
    public static readonly int SaltLength = 8; //Salt length in bytes
    private static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    private const int PBKDF2IterCount = 1000; // default for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
    private const int PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8; // 256 bits
    private const int SaltSize = 128 / 8; // 128 bits

    public static string DecryptString(string ciphertext, string passphrase)
    {
        var inputs = ciphertext.Split(":".ToCharArray(), 3);
        var iv = Convert.FromBase64String(inputs[0]); // Extract the IV
        var salt = Convert.FromBase64String(inputs[1]); // Extract the salt
        var ciphertextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputs[2]); // Extract the ciphertext

        // Derive the key from the supplied passphrase and extracted salt
        byte[] key = DeriveKeyFromPassphrase(passphrase, salt);

        // Decrypt
        byte[] plaintext = DoCryptoOperation(ciphertextBytes, key, iv, false);

        // Return the decrypted string
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext);
    }

    public static string EncryptString(string plaintext, string passphrase)
    {
        var salt = GenerateRandomBytes(SaltLength); // Random salt
        var iv = GenerateRandomBytes(16); // AES is always a 128-bit block size
        var key = DeriveKeyFromPassphrase(passphrase, salt); // Derive the key from the passphrase

        // Encrypt
        var ciphertext = DoCryptoOperation(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext), key, iv, true);

        // Return the formatted string
        return String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", Convert.ToBase64String(iv), Convert.ToBase64String(salt), Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext));
    }

    private static byte[] DeriveKeyFromPassphrase(string passphrase, byte[] salt, int iterationCount = 2000)
    {
        var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, salt, iterationCount);  //PBKDF2

        return keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(KeyLengthBits / 8);
    }

    private static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int lengthBytes)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[lengthBytes];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);

        return bytes;
    }

    // This function does both encryption and decryption, depending on the value of the "encrypt" parameter
    private static byte[] DoCryptoOperation(byte[] inputData, byte[] key, byte[] iv, bool encrypt)
    {
        byte[] output;

        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var cryptoTransform = encrypt ? aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv) : aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                cs.Write(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);

            output = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

If I publish this code and encrypt data and then decrypt it, there's no problem. I correctly receive the unencrypted data. If I rebuild my application without making any changes, then publish it again without re-encrypting the data, (it's already encrypted at this point), I'm unable to decrypt it. It just returns the encrypted strings.

Why would re-publishing to the same server to this? Should I be using a different approach? If so, please recommend that different approach.

Thanks

Comment: It *looks* like you are regenerating the secret key at every restart of the application. Are you sure that after you redeploy you get the same encrypted string? Or a different encrypted string?

Comment: As of now, the passphrase is stored in the appSettings of the config file. So that definitely is not changing. I've verified that the output of the DecryptString method returns the exact encrypted value that is in the database.